# How to set all items from a file into a dict

Tags: python

I have a File to define items

```
# Items.py

class items:
    def __init__(self, name, can_sell):
        self.name = name
        self.can_sell = can_sell

item_1 = item('sword', True) #You can sell this item
item_2 = item('shield', False) #You cant sell this item
```

and a file to sell items

```
# Sell.py

import Items as item_file

class sell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = #all items in item.py (dictionary)
        self.inv = #all items in item.py (dictionary)

    def sell_function(self):
        print("SELL 'item_name' or EXIT")        
        player_input = input(">  ")
        if player_input == "EXIT":
            exit()
        elif "SELL" in player_input:
            selling_item = player_input.split(' ')][-1]
            if selling_item in self.inv:
                if self.inv[selling_item]['can_sell'] is True:
                    self.inv.pop(selling_item)
            else:
                print("You dont have such item")
                exit()
```

How can I code the following part?
`self.items = #all items in item.py (dictionary)`

I have tried
`self.items = {item for item in item_file}`
but it returns
`TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable`

I know the `for line in item_file` method, but it would get the class lines too.
How can I just get the items in the file?

Comment: _What_ dictionary? Something like `{attr: value for attr in dir(item_file) if isinstance(value := getattr(item_file, attr), item_file.items)}` would work, once the obvious typos are fixed, but why not make `Items` responsible for creating and exposing an appropriate mapping, rather than individual variables (`created_items = dict(item_1=items('sword', true), ...)`?

Comment: But I'm planning on making hundreds of items, to do (created_items = dict(item_1 = items('sword', true), ...) it would look messy

Comment: I recommend: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: Messier that what you have to do to get all of those individual variables back into the dictionary you wanted to start with?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be starting to construct some weird structure of your program. You might want to consider if it is a logical approach to have a class for some action like selling. It seems more like an action(so method) one would do, not an object.

In any case, you can use class attribute to store all new objects of that class created:

```
class Item:
    all_items = []
    def __init__(self, name, can_sell):
        self.name = name
        self.can_sell = can_sell
        self.all_items.append(self)

item_1 = Item('sword', True) #You can sell this item
item_2 = Item('shield', False) #You cant sell this item

print([i.name for i in Item.all_items])

class Sell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = Item.all_items

a = Sell()

print([i.name for i in a.items])
```

As you can see that variable `all_items` is defined outside `__init__` function, so it belongs to the class itself and not instances. You would access it form the class and not its instances as well so `Item.all_items`

Note that it is confusing when you call classes with variable name convention. You [have to name classes in UpperCamelCase](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names).

Once again, what's the logic of Item class containing all the items?.. I am not sure. Maybe you might want to have some sort of a class for inventory that would contain items and it would track all items. And then maybe you could sell items from one inventory to another or something like that. I think it might be logical to represent real concepts of objects with Python objects so it is easier to think about the processes and data in your program.